# How to create key bindings that apply on in a quickfix buffer?

Tags: vimscript, neovim

The autoload command can be used to execute code depending on a range of events and filetypes.

When I list the active buffers, the buffer hosting the quickfix window has what seems to be a unique first and last char in the `%a-` tag...  Not to mention, has the name "[Quickfix List]".

The task: I want to set a key binding that applies only to a quickfix window.  I can accomplish the task based on the filetype.

The question: What is a robust approach to accomplish the same for a buffer in a quickfix window? i.e., have key bindings that only apply to the quickfix window.

Thank you in advance to anyone with ideas on how to proceed.

- E

Comment: I usually prefer ftplugins

Comment: I use a ftplugin to identify and sometimes augment what I do in a filetype-specific autocommand.  Is there a way to use a ftplugin to identify quickfix?

Comment: The filetype is `qf`

Comment: @LucHermitte  Exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you!

Comment: Whilst your question has been answered for future reference you can use `:set filetype?` to query the current `filetype`, or indeed any option.

Comment: Thank you @user32264.  I use that command often-enough.  However, I did not think to use it while in the quickcheck window until now! :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@LucHermitte provided the answer I was looking for.

Quickcheck has a filetype = qf.

Thank you!

-E

Comment: Also make sure you use [`:map <buffer>`](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#%3Amap-%3Cbuffer%3E) for mappings relevant to a single buffer (or filetype, since filetype mappings are applied every time a buffer is set to that specific filetype.)